# IonList separation line rendered to short

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I added the following list view to my app:

```
    <IonList>
  <IonItem>
    <IonLabel>Animierte Icons</IonLabel>
    <IonToggle color="success"></IonToggle>
  </IonItem>
  <IonItem>
    <IonLabel>Stadt</IonLabel>
    <IonSelect placeholder={"Stadt"} value>
      <IonSelectOption value="Berlin">Berlin</IonSelectOption>
    </IonSelect>
  </IonItem>
  <IonItem>
    <IonLabel>Vorhersage (Tage)</IonLabel>
    <IonSelect placeholder={"Tage"}>
      <IonSelectOption value="0">0</IonSelectOption>
    </IonSelect>
  </IonItem>
</IonList>
```

Everything works fine, but the separation line between the first and the second `IonItem` does not go as far as the other ones (see screenshot, marked in yellow). This problem only appears on when opened on Android or in the Browser, on iOS, everything is fine.

[image: Screenshot of the faulty list]

The Ion list is placed within a `IonCardContent`, but the problem is still there when the list is rendered outside of the card. Is ther a reason for this or is it a bug?
Thank you for your help and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the full component and if there is any ohter style-element above, which takes place, but you can try this:

```
<ion-list **lines="full"**>
 ...
</ion-list>
```